# Can't get thumbnail category - Magento 2.1.6

Tags: thumbnail

I checked quite many threads about this topic but was not able to solve the issue. When I open a category overview I don't get the thumbnails. Opening the product details I can see the main image and the smaller images in the slider below. So that shouldn't be any permission issues. Magento also generates the cache directory with 4 different image sizes.

My url to the thumbnail is:

```
pub/media/catalog/product/cache/f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/a/a/aaa_5_2_3.jpg
```

> find . -name "aaa_5_2_3.jpg"
>   pub/media/catalog/product/cache/f9c7fbe9b524c081a3ccf800cbd963eb/a/a/aaa_5_2_3.jpg
>   pub/media/catalog/product/cache/75eed2686e01eb22cb4050b2f40ddf97/a/a/aaa_5_2_3.jpg
>   pub/media/catalog/product/cache/0f831c1845fc143d00d6d1ebc49f446a/a/a/aaa_5_2_3.jpg
>   pub/media/catalog/product/cache/afad95d7734d2fa6d0a8ba78597182b7/a/a/aaa_5_2_3.jpg

I guess the identifier `(=f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857)` is wrong. Where does it come from? I tried to find the php file where the path is generated but couldn't find it.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy didn't help either. That's why I think the identifier is wrong.

I migrated the data from **Magento 1.7.0.2** with the migration tool and copied the directory public/media/catalog to pub/media/catalog.

Maybe somebody can help me out, I'm quite new to magento.

Comment: have you tried running the `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` command?

Comment: > php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
Notice: Undefined index: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product in /var/www/magento_2/magento2_led/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php on line 232

Seems like there is some problem, any idea?

Comment: yup. delete `var/generation` and `var/di` folders and set 777 permissions on the var folder

Comment: resizing still takes a while. Will let you know if that worked. thx a lot for your help!

Comment: @alex-dinca: Thank a lot, thumbnails appeared ;) If you reply I can give you the credits.
Are you willing to explain what happened? Apparently the **catalog:image:resize** resizes the images but I had resized images ... ? I like to understand things :D

Comment: I added an answer to the question so you can accept it :) As to what specifically happened in your case it may depend on multiple factors and it would be difficult for me to understand without being able to reproduce the issue. And so far I had no luck in doing so

Comment: thx a lot for your help! If you would have had a quick answer it would have been great but it's not that important, it works now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the image resize command to pre-generate all necessary resizes.

`php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`

This command gets all the images sizes that have been defined in the theme XML and pregenerates the images in their correct folders.

You can also check the command documentation for more information http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html